# Angular 5 HttpResponse status 412 not catched

Tags: angular, http, http-status-codes

In my backend, if some condition isnt true, i put in HttpStatus 412 (PRECONDITION_FAILED) :

```js
catch (StaticWeightModeNoObjectPresentException e) {
  LOGGER.debug("startProd:HttpStatus.PRECONDITION_FAILED: "+ BUNDLE.getString("controller.start.prod.ko"));
  response.setStatus(HttpStatus.PRECONDITION_FAILED.value());
  return null;
}
```

In my front page, I have this code :

```js
this.productionService.startProd('ETIQUETTE', +this.total).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res.status);
      if (res.status === 201 || res.status === 200) {
        console.debug('print Stickers is started !', res);
      } 
    },
      (error) => {
        console.log('startProd / error ', error);
        if (error.status === 412) {
          console.log('getWeight ===== 0');
          this.showToasterMessage('getWeightKO.title', 'getWeightKO.body', null);
        }
      },
      () => {

      });
```

I've add breakpoint in my JS and I see that when I've 412 error, I don't enter in (error) block

In my console, I can see the error like this:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/marqueo-connect-plus/api/v1/connectplus/startProd 412 (Echec de Pré-condition)
```

What I must to add for catching 412 status and showing the correct message?

Comment: whats the type of error.status?

Comment: Euhh , i dont know if i can write (error.status), i add it by me, i cant access to console.log before this instruction

Comment: ok what does the error object look like? is it even hitting the code console.log('startProd / error ', error);

Comment: As  i say before, i cant access to this instruction when i debug, i hav put breakpoint, the only access that i've is in the last (). (res) and (error) no access if i've HttpStatus 412

Comment: How about an else-block after your first if-block and if the res.status === 412 either handle it there or throw an error if you must?
I don't think 4xx status is an error as far as your observable is concerned.

Comment: If i add else in first if block, i got undefined (for res variable). Because when i put the status 412 in backend i return null

Comment: Just to be sure: you put the else -after- and not -in- the first if block, right?
Anyhow, what you are doing is not throwing an error. You are merely passing a status that an error occurred. To your observable, that is not an error and it will not throw an exception.
You need to handle that case according to how you dealt with it in the backend.
From what I can gather here is that you return null, then check for null in the else block.

Comment: For the else, i tried in the two if, i test this also : if (res.status === 201 || res.status === 200) {
        console.debug('print Stickers is started !', res);
      } else if (res === 'undefined') {
        console.log('startProd functional error ');
      }
i doesnt work

Comment: What about res === undefined or res === null.
I'm assuming the later as you are setting it to null on the backend.
You could also just add a break point on the else-if to see what res actually is.

Comment: I check this also, i cant access to the block with this condition, i'll try to put something in the response, after i check the status